# jQuery UI Dialog fires only on second link in carousel

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, coldfusion

In my page I have a carousel that displays short descriptions of products on sale (specials). When a user clicks the item in the carousel a UI dialog should pop open with the full product description based on the href in the carousel item.

If I click on the second item that shows up in the carousel a UI dialog shows up and loads the page content as it should. But, if I click on the first item in the carousel then it goes directly to the href.

Can anyone see what may be causing this strange behavior?

*EDIT* The code for handling the UI dialog is wrapped in the `$document.ready` function if that matters.

Here's the carousel in the page:

```
<div id="scroller">
    <div class="slideshow">
      <ul>
      <cfloop query="qScrollers">
        <li>
        <cfset product = #qScrollers.isproduct#>
        <cfif product IS true>
            <cfset ref = "editProduct.cfm?pid=" & #qScrollers.link#>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset ref = "specials_backup.cfm?item=" & #qScrollers.link#>
        </cfif>
          <a class="specials" href="<cfoutput>#ref#</cfoutput>" title="<cfoutput>#qScrollers.title#</cfoutput>">
          <p><cfoutput>#qScrollers.line1#</cfoutput></p>
          <h1><cfoutput>#qScrollers.line2#</cfoutput></h1>
          <p><cfoutput>#qScrollers.line3#</cfoutput></p>
          <h2><cfoutput>#qScrollers.line4#</cfoutput></h2></a>
          </a>
        </li>
      </cfloop>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And the script to pop the UI:

```
$('.specials').click(function() {
    var $link = $(this);
    var $dims = $link.attr('name');
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .load($link.attr('href'))
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            title: $link.attr('title'),
            width: 1024,
            height: 850
        });

    $dialog.dialog('open');
    return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently, it' was all a timing issue. I placed the jQuery code outside of the `$(document).ready` function and everything works like a charm.

So, here's the fix as I see it. If anyone has a better solution, please feel free to jump in.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//...all my other jQuery stuff here//
});

function createScroller(){
$('.specials').click(function() {
    var $link = $(this);
    //var $dims = $link.attr('name');
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .load($link.attr('href'))
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            title: $link.attr('title'),
            width: 1024,
            height: 850
        });

    $dialog.dialog('open');
    return false;
    }); 
}

window.onload = createScroller;
```

Answer (score 0):

move this

```
.dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            title: $link.attr('title'),
            width: 1024,
            height: 850
        })
```

to `.load` `callback`

Comment: When I move that to the callback it only changes when the UI dialog loads, when it does load correctly. If I click on the carousel item just as it stops easing in, I still have the same problem of it navigating to the link and not firing the UI dialog...